# Change the border color of tr and td

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am trying to make the border for a table look something like the picture attached however it does not implement the border colors or anything. It might be something to do with the Bootstrap 'table' class.

Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" id="left-info" > 17 SEPTEMBER</span>
                </td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

css:

```
table{
padding: 10px !important;
background-color: #575757 !important;
}

tr{
background-color: #575757;
border-top: 10px!important;
border-top-color: #383D3D !important;

}

td{
border-left: 3px !important;
border-left-color: #383D3D !important;
}
```

[image: what I want the end result to be]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
table{
border-collapse: collapse;
background-color: red;
}
tr{
background-color: #575757;
border-top: 10px solid #383D3D !important;
}
td{
    padding:10px;
border-left: 3px solid green !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" id="left-info" > 17 SEPTEMBER</span>
                </td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't see any image attached. But am hoping this is what your in search off !
Try giving separate ID for each of TR and TD, then define their color in CSS !
Like shown in below example,

```
<table>

<tr id="one">
<td><td><td></td>
</tr>

<tr id="two">
<td><td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>

</table>

#one td{
border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the border-type as `solid` in your css. Without **type**, border styles *never work*.

CSS:

```
table{
 padding: 10px !important;
 background-color: #575757 !important;
}

tr{
 background-color: #575757;
 border-top: solid 10px!important;
 border-top-color: #383D3D !important;
}

td{
 border-left: solid 3px !important;
 border-left-color: #383D3D !important;
}
```

Here's a working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ko8v7p4j/).

Answer (score 0):

i think this code work for you :

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>

            <td id="halfborder">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" id="left-info1" > 17 SEPTEMBER</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" id="left-info2" > 17 SEPTEMBER</span>
            </td>

         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and style :

```
#left-info1 {
    border-right:1px solid #999;
}
td {     padding:0px 10px;    }

.table {
    background-color:#333;
    padding:10px 0;
}
```